# How would $x \notin (B \setminus C)$ be written out?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it correct form to say:

$x \notin (x \in B \land x \notin C)$?

Comment: If you replace your parentheses with brackets and prelude your statement with x|     then you have a statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

$(x \in B \land x \notin C)$ (part of your expression) is a correct way of writing $x \in B-C$. Now, just negate that. 
Use [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: So I can write it as $(x \notin B \lor x \in C)$? Is that equivalent to $x \notin (B - C)$?

Comment: @JamesMitchell Yes, precisely! If it is not in $B$ minus $C$, then either it is not in $B$ at all, or else it is inside $C$, or both.